# Does a "withdrawal of application for admission" constitute a "refused admission" in the US?

Tags: united-states, immigration

In 2001 I attempted to re-enter the US after vacationing abroad. I had been working in the US and had forgotten that my H1-B was expired and in the process of being renewed. At the border, I was told that I couldn't re-enter the US and I signed a "withdrawal of application for admission" form. I was told by the immigration officers that this was an alternative to being deported which would not constitute a "refused admission".

Later I got my visa renewed and was able to re-enter the US. I am now a permanent resident.

What should I answer on official forms that ask "have you ever been refused entry to the US"?

Comment: I think this is okay as a "what does the law say" information question, and you absolutely should not act as though you're getting reliable legal advice.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you have been refused entry. But you have not been "removed".

Comment: Can you give any references for this?  In particular, it doesn't seem to make sense for someone to withdraw their application for admission if that application has already been considered and refused.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Here is an article that summarizes it: http://www.borderimmigrationlawyer.com/withdrawal-of-application-for/

Comment: I didn't see where that article says that a withdrawal is considered "refused entry".  In fact the word "refuse" doesn't appear in the article at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Allowing you to withdraw your application for admission is only something they do after they deny you entry, and is a benefit offered to you in their discretion to allow you to avoid removal. If there was no denial of entry, then there would be no point for this. This is all very obvious.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not obvious to me, and I would be more convinced by a source than a logical argument.